# Совместить и чередовать строки в Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть в notepad++ такая возможность - из двух кусков текста(или файлов) брать по строке поочерёдно и чередовать таким образом:

```
1 строка из 1 текста
1 строка из 2 текста
2 строка из 1 текста
2 строка из 2 текста
итд
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Довольно сложный способ нашелся тут - https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14965/combine-2-texts-line-by-line

Проставляем цифры (alt-c), совмещаем 2 файла, включаем сортировку, заменяем первые 2 числа (?-s)^.{2}(.*?\R) на \1

Answer (score 1):

> ## Внимание!
> Этот способ НЕ работает, если встречаются пустые строки.

[image: Скриншот]

1. Вставляем текст из двух файлов один за другим.

   ```
   Строка 1 из текста 1
   Строка 2 из текста 1
   Строка 3 из текста 1
   Строка 4 из текста 1
   Строка 1 из текста 2
   Строка 2 из текста 2
   Строка 3 из текста 2
   Строка 4 из текста 2
   ```
2. Обязательно в конце файла удаляем перевод строки.
3. Обращаем внимание, на строке с каким номером заканчивается первый файл. Из него вычитаем 1 - в примере получится `3`:

   [image: скриншот строк]
4. Обязательно ставим курсор в начало файла (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>).
5. В диалоге замены отмечаем <kbd>Регулярн. выражения</kbd> и НЕ отмечаем <kbd>и новые строки</kbd>.
6. Заменяем (предварительно заменив `3` на число из пункта 3)

   ```
   (^.*$\r?\n?)(?=(?:^.*$\r?\n?){3}(^.*$\r?\n?))|(.|\r|\n)*
   ```

   на

   ```
   $1$2
   ```
7. Готово.

Answer (score 1):

Да, спасибо, но вот как раз пустые строки есть.
В этом случае работает такой запрос:

```
(?s)^~~~.+|(?-s)^.*\R(?=(?:.*\R){3}(^.*\R))
```

меняем на

```
?1$0\1
```

Превращает вот такой текст

```
abc1
abc2
abc2
~~~~~
абв1
абв2
абв3
```

В то что нужно

```
abc1
абв1
abc2
абв2
abc2
абв3
```

Вместо 3 подставляем число строк до ~~~~~~

Только пропадает последняя строка, нужно чтобы после абв3 шла еще пустая строка, тогда всё норм будет

Подсмотрел тут https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14965/combine-2-texts-line-by-line/6

Comment: С пустыми строками надо вместо `\r?\n?` писать что-то вроде `(?:\r\n|\r|\n)`, но я не уверен - надо порверить. Но тот подход тоже должен работать, если допилить. А другой вариант - сделать ещё пару замен - сначала добавить что-то в начало всех строк (`^` => `0`), чтобы они все стали непутсыми, а потом убрать (`^0` => пусто).